# Call to SetTextJustification function - win32 program

Tags: c++, winapi

Can someone explain to me why this code does not work?

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
TCHAR str[] = _T("An example of SetTextJustification function");
```

the code in the message loop:

```
case WM_PAINT: 
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    if(!SetTextJustification(hdc, 40, 4));
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to SetTextJustification failed!"), _T("Error"), NULL);
    }

    TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, str, _tcslen(str));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens - does it fail, what's the error?  Does it draw wrong? I'm sure it's pretty obvious to you, but we can't see the screen you are looking at when this is running. And it wouldn't be the first time someone thinks something doesn't work, but it's just "wrong expectation", in other words, using it wrong.

Comment: When I run it, shown the message box, and it says that the function returns false.

Comment: And `GetLastError()` gives what?

Comment: So add a call to "GetLastError()" to your code, and see what it gives you. You can probably just have int error = GetLastError(); and set a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: GDI functions do not set the error code.  The function works fine when I try it in a boilerplate Win32 project, you'll need to provide a better repro project that exhibits this problem.

Comment: Hans - When you running my code, not shown you the message box?